# PowerApps Form Validation - Not on Submit

Tags: sharepoint-online, validation, powerapps-forms, syntax, function

I have an App (PowerApps) that includes 8 different Forms on 8 different screens that the User freely navigates and fills out info.  Among these Forms are several different Required Fields.  I'd like to add a "Validation Check" button at the bottom of each form that the User can click as they go to make sure the required fields are all filled in.  I can't just go with SubmitForm for this Button, because I want this Button to only perform a validation check, not submit any data (I have a final screen with a separate Submit function).  I've tried setting a Variable (varRequiredCheck) for the Fill color of one of the required fields' datacardvalue, but that doesn't really seem to work.

Any advice or direction would be super helpful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your app, I suggest you create a separate "Validation Screen".

**About Validation Screen**
Here, get all the variables as output text (skip colors and formats, barebone minimal is the best) for each validation case. Think as table summary or a report card for your design.

**Benefit**
Validation Screen is easy to make and troubleshooting is a breeze for any stages (dev, stage, and or production) because you can always come back to the validation screen (reusable) when users report issue and quickly resolve the issue.